# openpyxl Workbook theme colors not standard for Excel

Tags: excel, openpyxl, fill

I am trying to copy cell colors from one xlsx to another using python and openpyxl. Using:

```
cellInNewBook.fill = copy(cellInOriginalBook.fill)
```

works for doing this but for some reason the workbook I created using:

```
newBook = Workbook()
```

has different Theme Colors when I open it in Excel.

When I choose to edit a cell background color in my original xlsx it shows these Theme Colors:

[image]

However when I look at the same cell background dropdown options in Excel for the new workbook they are different, and as a result my copy is showing different colors because the index for each is different:

[image]

So I am concluding that the theme colors are being set by openpyxl's Workbook() and they are not the default that Excel would have. Is there a way to make the new Workbook match the Theme colors in the same order/positions as the original xlsx workbook?

Comment: Sure, you can, in theory, copy the theme settings from one workbook to another. There's no API for this but if you look at the source code it's fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

OpenPyXl treats 'theme color' and 'standard color' as separate attributes.
You can test this for yourself by doing:

```
print("Cell fill display:" wb.active(rowNumber, columnNumber).fill)
```

This will show a long output including parts that looks similar to:

> fgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object> Parameters: rgb=None,
> indexed=None, auto=None, theme=4, tint=0.7999816888943144,
> type='theme', ...

Notice how rgb is None but type at the end is 'theme' instead of 'rgb'.

If you wish to utilize 'theme' instead of standard (rgb) color, you'll need need to define a function that extracts the theme and tint and then stores them together as a string or a dictionary item.

```
wb.active(rowNumber, columnNumber).fill.fgColor.theme)
wb.active(rowNumber, columnNumber).fill.fgColor.tint)
```